# Github Pages Automatically assigned domain instead of using my username

Tags: github-pages

Whenever I used GH pages in the past, when I deploy it would use my username as the URL. So in this case it should be http://William9601/weather-app-21/. However, since I acquired a domain it automatically uses that as the URL so it is now http://qreceipts.me/weather-app-21/.

How can I change this so it does not use the qreceipts domain? Not sure why it automatically uses that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open your repo
2. Click on settings
3. click in the link under the tab GitHub Pages

Since you have set up your domain all GitHub pages repos will be used under that please change the qreceipts repo domain to qreceipts.me and don't save your domain for GitHub.

This should solve your issue If this does not solve try contacting GitHub they will have more information.

If this answers your question please mark this as answer.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I contacted Github and turns out that my top level repo with .github.io had a CNAME file with my custom domain in it. So, any other repos I created were being assigned that domain

Comment: I am glad You found this useful so could you please mark this as the answer so It can help other people?

Comment: I am sure other people will also have the same question and might not click because it is not a verified answer.

Answer (score 1):

OK so for anyone else getting this problem, the fine people at Github gave me the answer. My top level repo with .github.io extension had a CNAME file with my custom domain in it. So, any other repos I created were being assigned that domain.

When I linked the domain website with my Github account this must have automatically added the CNAME file.

As a solution, you can remove the custom domain by either deleting the CNAME file or removing it from the Pages section of the repository settings.